# "Fetch some water in a quiver" or "Get some water in a quiver"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

What is the most effective and correct way to use the sentences?

1)  He requested his friend to **fetch some water in a quiver**.

2)  He requested his friend to **get some water in a quiver**.

Is there any similarity in both two sentences?
  or they are different  in their use?

Comment: The odd thing about those sentences is not the verb, but your choice of the word *quiver*, which is a pouch used to carry arrows. Why would you fetch water with a quiver? Where did you learn this word, and why are you using it here?

Comment: @JSB oh, I was watching a Episode of Mahabharata in a T.V. and i got it there the Yudhishthira requested Nakula to fetch some water in a quiver. then I quizzed ?  why it couldn't be get some water in a quiver.from my point of view both are same. but there is a little  bit of confusion.

Comment: @JSBⰀⰐⰃⰔ Weird how close *fetch* is to words like *fletch*, *fletcher*, and *fletchery*, where one might well expect to find *quivers*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Fetch* and *get* mean the same thing in these sentences. [Fetch](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fetch) means that you are going to get something, and bring it back. Get ([meaning 3 here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/get)) doesn't necessarily mean that you are bringing it back.

Comment: Also, fetch is much less common and sounds old-fashioned.

Comment: I live in SE US, @Mitch :)

Comment: Is "fetch" commonly used in the south east? Or is that just self-deprecating humor?

Comment: @JeffSahol : i got it because the Nakula was supposed to get water back to his brothers.

Comment: "Fetch" is commonly used in the southeast, @Jay, at least around where I live. I'd say "get" is the norm in the city but as you get into the mountains or the country, you are more likely to hear "fetch".

Comment: @JeffSahol: OK then I amend to say '....in Standard American English'

Comment: Those who feel 'fetch' is old-fasioned need to fetch a new block of data with zero latency.

Comment: I also agree that "fetch" is not old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

A bigger problem is the misuse of 'request'.

You can request a favour or thing ~ "He requested a room with a sea view"

or request to have something ~ "He requested to be allowed a longer time"

or request that something happens ~ "He requested that they all bring their own cameras"

but not request a friend to do something. That should be 'ask'.

Try "he requested that his friend fetch/get some water..."

Answer (score 1):

In your contention that *fetch* and *get* are synonyms, you are thinking of the meaning 'to bring'.

However, *fetch* is used in the sense of 'go and bring (or carry back)'.

Remember Jack and Jill went ... to fetch a pail of water, not 'to bring'?

*Get* is slightly tricky -- it is used in either sense.

Answer (score -2):

fetch pictures searching before getting. if you go to a particular place to get water, you did not 'fetch' it, because you did not search to get it.

Comment: As a native North American English speaker, this is not how I understand the word "fetch".  In fact, "fetch" more often connotes that one already knows where the desired object is.